# Access SQL How do I update on duplicates?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Right now I have some Access SQL that can find duplicates in my table. I'm trying to write a separate UPDATE command that will update a field associated with these duplicates.

```
UPDATE T 
    SET BAD_CODES = BAD_CODES  & 'D'
    FROM work AS T 
    JOIN (SELECT DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE, COUNT(*)
          FROM work                      
          GROUP BY DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
          ) AS S
      ON  T.DIVISION = S.DIVISION
      AND T.FIPS_COUNTY_CODE = S.FIPS_COUNTY_CODE
      AND T.LAST = S.LAST
      AND T.SUFFIX = S.SUFFIX
      AND T.FIRST = S.FIRST
      AND T.TITLE = S.TITLE
      AND T.BIRTHDATE = S.BIRTHDATE
```

I think this is close to what I need, but I get a syntax error (missing operator) that I can't seem to figure out. What's wrong with my SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE work T INNER JOIN
      (/* Subquery */) AS S
      ON  T.DIVISION = S.DIVISION
      AND T.FIPS_COUNTY_CODE = S.FIPS_COUNTY_CODE
      AND T.LAST = S.LAST
      AND T.SUFFIX = S.SUFFIX
      AND T.FIRST = S.FIRST
      AND T.TITLE = S.TITLE
      AND T.BIRTHDATE = S.BIRTHDATE
SET T.BAD_CODES = T.BAD_CODES  & 'D'
```

Access doesn't allow aggregated view to be updated. You'll have to create a temp table and update using it and later drop it.

Comment: Now it just says syntax error (before it said syntax error and would give me the block where the error was, which wasn't very helpful since it was 95% of the block).

Comment: I know that isn't helpful, but it literally does not say. It just pops up with a box that says "Syntax Error".

Comment: @rohan Can you try now?

Comment: Now it says "operation must use an updateable query" 

Any ideas?

Comment: Access doesn't allow aggregated view to be updated. You'll have to create a temp table and update using it and later drop it.

Comment: I see. I just need to make a temp DB to copy the data to?

Comment: You can create the table with the result of the subquery (having group by's) and then use that table instead of subquery in the statement I have given in the answer

Comment: Is it possible to create that temp table on the fly, and then delete it after the process?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to go about this exactly